# Stop Illustrator from snapping to other artboards?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment, grids

So i'm working in Illustrator and I when I move something it tries to align it to something from another artboard as opposed to anything in actually in my current art board. Is there a setting to where I can lock things to their respective art boards? Its frustrating to go locking layers when there may just be a setting to stop it all together im hoping?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, I don't believe there's a setting for that.

You can do artboard-specific guides (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> or choose the Artboard Tool, then drag guides directly into the selected artboard), but even then an object on Artboard #1 will try to snap to a guide on Artboard #2 if they're adjacent.

**There's a maybe-useful trick, though:** if the other artboards are off-screen — by zooming or otherwise positioning the work area so you can only see one artboard — Illustrator won't try to snap things to objects on those artboards. It should only snap to visible objects.

Answer (score 0):

My solution I came up with (and the most direct one) was to choose the correct artboard in the artboard panel you will find next to the layers panel. Then the alignment will take effect relative to the selected artboard.